# Why is the second for loop more than two times slower than the first one?

Tags: palindrome

I wrote this function to check if any substring of an input string is palindrome. I expected the following two versions of code to take exactly the same amount of time since the logic is very similar.  However, version 1 takes about 151 milliseconds whereas version 2 takes more than 350 milliseconds on my test input.

Furthermore, if I replace the setPalindrome  with cout << "" << endl;, the running time of the two versions is then exactly the same.

I am wondering what is causing the big time difference in the case of setPalindrome ?

My test input is string s = "kwtbjmsjvbrwriqwxadwnufplszhqccayvdhhvscxjaqsrmrrqngmuvxnugdzjfxeihogzsdjtvdmkudckjoggltcuybddbjoizu";

```
void setPalindrome(string s, int start, int length, map<pair<int, int>, bool>& palindrome){

   auto key = make_pair(start, length);

   // no key in map

   if (palindrome.find(key) == palindrome.end()){

         if (s[start] == s[start + length - 1] && length >= 3){

                palindrome[key] = palindrome[make_pair(start + 1, length - 2)];

         }

         else if (s[start] == s[start + length - 1] && length <= 2){

                palindrome[key] = true;

         }

         else{

                palindrome[key] = false;

         }

   }
```

}

Version 1:

```
int minCut(string s) {

   int size = s.size();

   map<pair<int, int>, bool> palindrome;

   vector<int> minCuts;



   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

         palindrome[make_pair(i, 1)] = true;

         minCuts.push_back(size - i - 1);

   }



   for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--){

          for (int j = 2; i + j <= size; j++){

                setPalindrome(s, i, j, palindrome);

          }

   }

   return 0;
```

}

Version 2:

```
int minCut(string s) {

   int size = s.size();

   map<pair<int, int>, bool> palindrome;

   vector<int> minCuts;



   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

         palindrome[make_pair(i, 1)] = true;

         minCuts.push_back(size - i - 1);

   }



   for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--){

         for (int j = size - i; j >= 2; j--){

                setPalindrome(s, i, j, palindrome);

         }

   }

   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of such a time difference would be the map you are using. Because c++ internally uses a balanced tree data structure, the order that you insert to the tree matters.

Your version two is inserting into the tree in a strictly decreasing order, thus causing the maximum number of balancing operations to take place. This could take significant amount of time.

Your version two also has the loop index messed up. Your should start from size - 1 instead of size.

```
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
         for (int j = size - i; j >= 2; j--){
                setPalindrome(s, i, j, palindrome);
         }
}
```